# Handling context in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I am transitioning into the realms of angular 2 and have decided to create a drag-and-drop component. So:

I have several variables with assigned types defined like so:

```
export class UploadComponent {
  image: Blob;
  reader: FileReader;
  ele: Element;
  cols: NodeList;
  dragSrcEl: Object;

  ...
}
```

And I have several functions attached to their corresponding listeners - here are the two functions in question:

```
handleDragStart(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('opaque');
    (() => { this.dragSrcEl = e; } )();

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this['innerHTML']);
  }
```

and

```
handleDrop(e) {
    if(e.stopPropagation)
      e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('this -> '+this );
    console.log('dragSrcEl -> '+(() => { this.dragSrcEl })());
  }
```

so when the user starts dragging the element we set the `this.dragSrcEl` class variable to `e`, but when I access it in the second function, even when using the wonderful arrow function, I get `undefined`. Why?

Isn't the use of the arrow function enough here to ensure that I access the correct context and access the correct variable? I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of OO javascript because I think this should work.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I have also tried calling it without the use of the IIFE like so:

```
this.dragSrcEl = e;
```

Comment: Is that typescript? It's definitely not ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target of a function bound as an event handler to a DOM event is the source DOM node itself.

If you want to modify an object in the handler then you need to make it available to the handler.

Either by closure, by binding an argument, or by binding the target.

e.g.

```
element.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart.bind(myComponent));
```

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#my-button');
button.addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

```html
<button id="my-button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Good answer that appears to have fixed it. Cheers for that

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create a IIFE

```
handleDragStart(e) {
    e.target.classList.remove('opaque');
    this.dragSrcEl = e; 

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this['innerHTML']);
  }

handleDrop(e) {
    if(e.stopPropagation)
      e.stopPropagation();

    console.log('this -> '+this );
    console.log('dragSrcEl -> '+this.dragSrcEl );
  }
```

Comment: This was actually my first attempt to use it but it returns the exact same undefined result